Why i can access dahsboard even when my login fail?
I’m having trouble with authentication where I have a Laravel backend and a Nuxt frontend. When I log in and log out successfully, everything works fine. The problem occurs when the login fails due to incorrect credentials, yet I’m still able to access the dashboard. Even though the login fails, I can see a new XSRF token being added in the browser’s Application tab. The issue is that I can access the dashboard and even the profile section, but when I try to log out, I get an error saying I’m unauthorized, which makes sense because the token wasn’t provided. However, for some reason, a session with the XSRF token is hanging around, causing me to be partially logged in even though I’ve entered incorrect login credentials. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? I’m new to REST APIs, so I’m probably doing something very wrong.
This is my useAuth.js
export default function useAuth() {
    const user = useState('auth-user', () => null)

    const { errorBag, transformValidationErrors, resetErrorBag } = useCustomError()

    const { api, csrf } = useAxios()

    async function me() {
        try {
            const data = await api.get("/api/me")
            user.value = data.data
        } catch (e) {
            user.value = null
            console.log("error")
        }
    }

    function login(userForm) {
        resetErrorBag()
        csrf().then(() => {
            api.post("/login", userForm).then(({ data }) => {

                user.value = data.user

                $fetch('/api/set-cookie', {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: { token: data.token }
                }).then(res => {
                    navigateTo("/dashboard")
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                transformValidationErrors(err.response)
            })
        })
    }


    function logout() {
        api.post("/api/logout").then(() => {
            user.value = null
            $fetch('/api/logout', {
                method: "POST",
            }).then(res => {
                navigateTo("/")
            })

        })
    }

    function register(userForm) {

        resetErrorBag()
        csrf().then(() => {
            api.post("/register", userForm).then(({ data }) => {
                //   verify email screen
            }).catch(err => {
                transformValidationErrors(err.response)
            })
        })
    }


    return { login, logout, register, errorBag, user, me }

}

this is my useAxios.js
import axios from "axios";

export default function useAxios(){

    const rtConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    let api = axios.create({
        baseURL: rtConfig.public.API_URL,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            // "Authorization:": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        withXSRFToken: true
    })



    async function csrf(){
        return await api.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie")
    }

    return {
        api, csrf
    }
}

guest middleware
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {


    const key = process.server ? 'token' : 'XSRF-TOKEN'

    const token = useCookie(key)


    if(token.value)
        return navigateTo('/')


  })
  

auth middlware
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {


    const key = process.server ? 'token' : 'XSRF-TOKEN'

    const token = useCookie(key)


    if(!token.value)
        return navigateTo('/')



  })

So even when I defined auth middleware for dashboard page lije this
definePageMeta({
    middleware: ['auth']
  })

I can still access it, but at all I'm not authorized. I don't understand where is mistake :/

An XSRF Token is not a Bearer Token or any kind of authentication ticket. EDIT: Ah, I'm wrong - apparently Laravel seems to (ab)use the concept of XSRF tokens (which are meant to only prevent unwarranted cross-site requests), but Laravel uses it for (some) kinds of positive authX too - that seems like a bad design to me....

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

@NicoHaase It's problem on side of JS.

Then please remove all irrelevant tags from your question

@NicoHaase yy done.

Laravel will almost always include XSRF-TOKEN cookie unless the request is from an exlucded path, when the route is define in web routes instead of api routes.
You can try this with this simple route:
Route::get('test', function () {
    return 'test';
});

web routes are stateful and api routes are stateless.
web routes by default have this middleware handling CSRF:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v11.23.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Configuration/Middleware.php#L446
That said, XSRF-TOKEN is not used for checking authentication.
More on here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf

What you can do instead is actually getting the user.
Your process then goes like:

always fetch user
check if user can access page via auth, guest, or no middleware

To do the always fetch user, since I assume you're most likely want to show the user data like in a User dropdown, and not just for authentication check, is to do it via Nuxt plugin.
Create plugins/auth.server.ts plugin:
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  try {
    const user = useUser()
    const response = await getUser()
    user.value = {
      id: response.id,
      name: response.name,
      email: response.email,
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof FetchError && error.response?.status === 401) {
      return
    }

    throw error
  }
})


Now user data should always be available throughout your Nuxt app.
In your authentication check middlwares, you can now do:
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
  const user = useUser()

  if (user.value === null) {
    return navigateTo('/login')
  }
})

and
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
  const user = useUser()

  if (user.value !== null) {
    // You can set this to anything you need
    return navigateTo('/dashboard')
  }
})


